# Notifications with AKKA and OSGi

Tags: websocket, akka, osgi

I've a OSGi based web application. The next feature I'd like to add is notifications. A simple box that appears in the browser. I've looked into this and it seems a combination of Akka and Websockets is the best way to go. Now, I'm looking for a simple example for my problem. Or is there another - easier - way to go?

Comment: You could use SSE (Server-Sent Events) instead of websockets (only server-to-client communication, but simpler and using standard HTTP protocol), and instead of AKKA you could try OSGi events

Comment: Hmm, okay, aware of a good example? As always with OSGi documentation is limited.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example Server Sent Events example in [OSGi enRoute EASSE example](https://github.com/osgi/osgi.enroute.examples/tree/master/osgi.enroute.examples.easse.application). This example is based on Server Sent Events.

The application sends an event to OSGi Event Admin the [Server Sent Event Bundle](https://github.com/osgi/osgi.enroute.bundles/tree/master/osgi.enroute.easse.simple.adapter) contains a servlet that handles the requests from Javascript. It dispatches matching Event Admin events to any Javascript requests. The Javascript code is in the web folder.

You should be able to checkout the workspace and run it all in Bndtools. If you're unfamiliar with OSGi enRoute, follow the [Quick Start Tutorial](http://enroute.osgi.org/qs/050-start.html)